# Model Class purposes and position in solution

Tags: c#, architecture, projects-and-solutions

I think that Model class has couple of variations.

1. Once fetched from repository - for example [this class](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Mapping.md)
2. Convert it to your app needs and hand it to the business logic - might be different class (loose couple of DB representation)
3. convert it before sending it to UI

where do you locate all those models? in one "Model" folder? or everyone in its own layer?

Comment: The question is not clear exactly but I think it has something to do with Reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's a Model, and m be located in DAL project
2. It's a BO (Business object), and might be located in BL (Business Logic) project
3. It's a ViewModel and might be located in presentation project (Web for example)

Comment: thanks. so in which layer would you put, for example the Converter class between Model and BO?

Comment: It is more like business logic - how to combine one or several entities to BO. It might be like BL project-BO folder for objects and BL project-Converters folder for your converters, and, for example BL project-Processor folder for business logic implementation, or smth. It's not a dogma, just use a common sense, nothing special. Also you may use IoC container and enclose convertor logic there.

Comment: mmm, for keep things in order - if I can use the Model class "as is" in the business level, is it recommended to anyway move it to BO object for the sake of layers isolation?

Comment: in short - it depends :) If you using a custom DAL with ADO and manually written objects - why not to use it as BO? You can add BO only for that ones, that not covered by DAL models. But is you use EF for example, in my mind it might be more comfortable to convert EF entities to something else.